# Get rid of all the unnecessary files that NuGet package has in it

Tags: .net, visual-studio, nuget

I am using NuGet AvalonDock package from https://www.nuget.org/packages/AvalonDock/ 
however, after the installation, my project's output directory contains about hundred of various documentation/localization files and dlls from AvalonDock that I don't require in my project, which really does make things a bit messy.

I only need two dlls.

I am wondering if there is a way to specify of what to include/exclude from the downloadable package, instead of manually deleting those files on each product release?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a way to do it built into the system. But make it part of your build script to remove the unneeded files. Then it won't be manual.

Comment: @inside It's not an extra step for you in the build/deployment process. Just the one time cost of modifying (or making) build scripts.

Comment: In my case I don't have release script, as it not needed at this point, so it is an extra step :)

Comment: @inside You're going to have to do *something*. A one time cost is not the same thing as an extra step in your process.

Comment: @inside I think you'd be better off not using the nuget package if it doesn't fit your needs. Just download the library and add the references manually, one time.

Comment: accepting the answer since I don't think there is actual solution